# span tag with and without content works differently

Tags: html, css

I have html code:

```
<ul>
     <li><span class="a">aaa</span><span class="b">bbb</span></li>
     <li><span class="a">aaa</span><span class="b">bbb</span></li>
     <li><span class="a">aaa</span><span class="b">bbb</span></li>
</ul>
```

and css:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #900;
}

.b {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #009;
}
```

Works fine if in both spans (`class="a"` and `class="b"`) are some content writed.

If remove text from `span class="b"`, now result is not desirable

http://jsfiddle.net/hm3sh/1/

Tell please why this happened ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to both spans; this should make them work as desired even if both have no content.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/hm3sh/2/

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/hm3sh/4/

```
.a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #900;
}

.b {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #009;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `float:left;` into span class a

http://jsfiddle.net/hm3sh/7/

Answer (score 0):

i tried to experiment with different situations after adding :

```
.a {
....
float:left;
....
}
```

it works well, specially with margin & padding set to 0 in `ul {...`.
i know there are other solutions but i think this one is minimal possible.